# Extract similar value and it's following details from different format of PDF using python library or any ML model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pdf-extraction

I need to extract patient name and their age and table contents of test details [For example Test name,unit,value] from different format of PDF.

I uploaded 2 images for reference from different format of PDF with similar value.

How can I extract and filter details for different format of PDF?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

From this I need to extract Test name,Result,Units and it's following content and also need to extract name,age.

Is there any possibilities to do that using python?

Comment: Extracting values and details from PDFs with different formats can be a challenging task due to the variety of structures and layouts that can be found in PDF documents. However, there are several Python libraries that can be used such as PyPDF2, pdfminer, and pdfplumber. Additionally, machine learning models such as NLP models can be used to extract relevant information from PDFs.

Comment: I used those library u mentioned ,I can extract but could not get or filter details as I want(I need to extract Test name,Result,Units and it's following content and also need to extract name,age.) @ghostlegend

Comment: Add your code so we can make changes